# How to get the last date in a range for each category

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to display the latest transaction date for each customer in Sheet 2 but can't seem to get it right in google sheets. Can anyone help me with the right formula?

Sheet 1:

[image]

Sheet2:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this [query](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage) formula:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A:C},"select max(Col1), Col3 where Col3 <> '' group by Col3", 1)
```

Paste it in Sheet2 cell A1.

Modify this formula to get custom headres:

`=QUERY({Sheet1!A:C},"select max(Col1), Col3 where Col3 <> '' group by Col3 label max(Col1) 'Latest Transaction Date'", 1)`

Comment: Hi i tried putting it in and it works. However what if i had other rows in sheet 1 above the table? do i just adjust Sheet1!A:C to Sheet1!A9:C9 if the headers are at row 9?

Comment: Better use open range `Sheet1!A9:C` in order to match new entered data

Comment: Still not working. Perhaps you can try on my sample sheet here

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18-2psWyPoSZiQzOWKk78LhhcIVk8P77wOPAwrTypQZM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: This works, you need adjust your range: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13VZKk4_h620pzhKol20HE_Uoejaj-f63bwfPxY5dbl4/edit?usp=sharing